# What is the advantage of using Option.map over Option.isEmpty and Option.get?

Tags: scala

I am a new to Scala coming from Java background, currently confused about the best practice considering `Option[T]`.

I feel like using `Option.map` is just more functional and beautiful, but this is not a good argument to convince other people. Sometimes, isEmpty check feels more straight forward thus more readable. Is there any objective advantages, or is it just personal preference?

Example:

Variation 1:

```
someOption.map{ value => 
  {
    //some lines of code
  }
} orElse(foo)
```

Variation 2:

```
if(someOption.isEmpty){
  foo
} else{
  val value = someOption.get
  //some lines of code
}
```

I intentionally excluded the options to use `fold` or pattern matching. I am simply not pleased by the idea of treating `Option` as a collection right now, and using pattern matching for a simple `isEmpty` check is an abuse of pattern matching IMHO. But no matter why I dislike these options, I want to keep the scope of this question to be the above two variations as named in the title.

Comment: The advantage is from the perspective of functional programming. You get to stay inside the monadic wrapper and chain your flow. This may seem similar in case of `Option` but if you think of something like `Future`, `isEmpty` is not going to help you at all.

Comment: Consider also the `fold` variant: `someOption.fold(foo)(value => ???)`. And the `match` variant: `someOption match { case Some(value) => ??? case None => foo }`

Comment: There is also third variation that I personally prefer.  `someOption match {case Some(object) => ... case None => ...}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> using pattern matching for a simple isEmpty check is an abuse of pattern matching IMHO

If you do just want an `isEmpty` check, `isEmpty`/`isDefined` is perfectly fine. But in your case you also want to get the value. And using pattern matching for this is not abuse; it's precisely the basic use-case. Using `get` allows to very easily make errors like forgetting to check `isDefined` or making the wrong check:

```
if(someOption.isEmpty){
  val value = someOption.get
  //some lines of code
} else{
  //some other lines
}
```

Hopefully testing would catch it, but there's no reason to settle for "hopefully".

Combinators (`map` and friends) are better than `get` for the same reason pattern matching is: they don't allow you to make this kind of mistake. Choosing between pattern matching and combinators is a different question. Generally combinators are preferred because they are more composable (as Yuval's answer explains). If you want to do something covered by a single combinator, I'd generally choose them; if you need a combination like `map ... getOrElse`, or a `fold` with multi-line branches, it depends on the specific case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error in code, corrected it. "Abuse" may be a strong word, I rather meant not very idomatic as pointed out by [ScalaDoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.Option). Still, it seems to be a good practical argument. Maybe you want to include case where it could go wrong in the answer?

Comment: Scaladoc says it's less idiomatic than using combinators (basically for reasons explained in Yuval's answer), but `get` is less idiomatic than pattern matching. It just doesn't even rate a mention on that page.

Answer (score 8):

> Is there any objective advantages, or is it just personal preference?

I think there's a thin line between objective advantages and personal preference. You cannot make one believe there is an absolute truth to either one.

The biggest advantage one gains from using the monadic nature of Scala constructs is *composition*. The ability to chain operations together without having to "worry" about the internal value is powerful, not only with `Option[T]`, but also working with `Future[T]`, `Try[T]`, `Either[A, B]` and going back and forth between them (also see [Monad Transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_transformer)).

Let's try and see how using predefined methods on `Option[T]` can help with control flow. For example, consider a case where you have an `Option[Int]` which you want to multiply only if it's greater than a value, otherwise return -1. In the imperative approach, we get:

```
val option: Option[Int] = generateOptionValue

var res: Int = if (option.isDefined) {
  val value = option.get
  if (value > 40) value * 2 else -1
} else -1
```

Using collections style method on `Option`, an equivalent would look like:

```
val result: Int = option
  .filter(_ > 40)
  .map(_ * 2)
  .getOrElse(-1)
```

Let's now consider a case for composition. Let's say we have an operation which might throw an exception. Additionaly, this operation may or may not yield a value. If it returns a value, we want to query a database with that value, otherwise, return an empty string.

A look at the imperative approach with a `try-catch` block:

```
var result: String = _
try {
  val maybeResult = dangerousMethod()
  if (maybeResult.isDefined) {
    result = queryDatabase(maybeResult.get)
  } else result = ""
}
catch {
  case NonFatal(e) => result = ""
}
```

Now let's consider using `scala.util.Try` along with an `Option[String]` and composing both together:

```
val result: String = Try(dangerousMethod())
  .toOption
  .flatten
  .map(queryDatabase)
  .getOrElse("")
```

I think this eventually boils down to which one can help you create clear control flow of your operations. Getting used to working with `Option[T].map` rather than `Option[T].get` will make your code *safer*.

To wrap up, I don't believe there's a single truth. I do believe that composition can lead to beautiful, readable, side effect deferring safe code and I'm all for it. I think the best way to show other people what you feel is by giving them examples as we just saw, and letting them feel for themselves the power they can leverage with these sets of tools.

Answer (score 1):

It seems similar to you in case of `Option` but just consider the case of `Future`. You will not be able to interact with the future's value after going out of `Future` monad.

```
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.concurrent.Promise
import scala.util.{Success, Try}

// create a promise which we will complete after sometime
val promise = Promise[String]();

// Now lets consider the future contained in this promise
val future = promise.future;

val byGet = if (!future.value.isEmpty) {
  val valTry = future.value.get
  valTry match {
    case Success(v) => v + " :: Added"
    case _ => "DEFAULT :: Added"
  }
}  else "DEFAULT :: Added"

val byMap = future.map(s => s + " :: Added")

// promise was completed now
promise.complete(Try("PROMISE"))


//Now lets print both values

println(byGet)
// DEFAULT :: Added

println(byMap)
// Success(PROMISE :: Added)
```